# Enable DataGrid Copy with Custom Columns

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate

I have a DataGrid where I have Custom Columns with Column Templates to insert special Tooltips. When doing that, how do I enable copying this data to clipboard?

XAML-Code of my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CapabilityGrid" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Variable">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource tooltipConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ClipboardContentBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.clipboardcontentbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets the binding object to use when getting or setting cell content for the clipboard.

so in XAML you can do

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Value}">
```

Comment: This is great - but can't seem to apply a string format onto that binding?

Comment: @Shumii I don't think you can. `StringFormat` will work only if destination is of a string type